# Formatting Timestamp In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to add directly into my database using phpMyAdmin and I want the id to be the current time so I'm using `TIMESTAMP`. The problem is that the output that I'm getting is `2014-07-19 15:37:32` where as I want it to be a string like `2147483647` (I think this is the day & time in seconds) so that I can use php to format it inside the web document.

How do I get it to place the string of numbers instead of the date format?

Comment: FYI, the MySQL date time format is easily reformatted in PHP using [`strtotime()`](http://uk3.php.net/strtotime) to create the second parameter in `date()`

Answer (score 1):

To get the seconds you can easily use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp_column) as yourformat;
```

I don't think it's a good idea to use this for identifying rows, because there could be easily more than one insert operation in just the same second. You better use a simple autoincrement column.

**Edit**

If your column should be an CHAR column you could do this with

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, ...) VALUES
(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS CHAR(10), ...);
```

But I would prefer to use an INTEGER type for your column instead of a string type.

The type TIMESTAMP is a MySQL timestamp, it's not the same as a string and not the same as a unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm wantning to do is insert it as a string, like if I was doing it with a php script I would use `$id= time()` to have a string of `2147483647`, what I'm getting is `2014-07-19 15:37:32`! How do I change this?

Comment: Actually, `time()` returns an int, not a string, anyway. See http://us3.php.net/time for details. Since you seem against using DATETIME, I favor VMai's approach of storing it as an INT in MySQL; there's no clear advantage to using a CHAR here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%d%m%Y' )
```

Use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) method to get the time in `19072014` date-month-year

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, ...) VALUES
(DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%d%m%Y' ) , ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TIMESTAMP is what you think it is. Have you seen the MySQL documentation on [data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html)?

I think you should use DATETIME. VMai has a good approach if you're set on using the seconds-since-epoch system (the suggestion to store it as an INT), but since you're storing a date and time in the database, you should take advantage of the data type that's designed to store a date and time :-) If you store it as a DATETIME you get some extra benefits (human readable, ability to apply time zones and daylight saving/standard time conversions, and so on), and you could cast it as a UNIX_TYPESTAMP in your SELECT so your application doesn't need to be changed.

I've also found http://www.developwebsites.net/choose-optimal-mysql-data-type/ to be quite useful.